# Is Quicktime always pre-installed on the Macintosh OS?

Tags: macos, mac, quicktime

Does the Mac come with Quicktime pre-installed?
If so, what OS version (minimum) could be expected to have come with it pre-installed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every version of Mac OS X has QuickTime. QuickTime *Pro* is/was an optional paid extra, which included extra codecs and additional functionality.

The situation with "classic" Mac OS was rather more complicated, but I'm guessing you only care about OS X.

Comment: Additionally Mac OS X 10.6 came with QuickTime X installed, but the install disk also came with 7.6 so it was possible to have two versions of QuickTime installed. Can't remember the reason for needing the other version. Something to do with providing compatibility for older APIs or something.

Comment: One reason for the continued existence of QuickTime 7, I'd imagine, is to allow the people who bought the Pro licence and/or the QuickTime MPEG2 plugin to continue to use them -- some of those features have no equivalent in the simpler Quicktime X application.